# iOS App Notification with Parse.com

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I have two iOS apps connected with one [Parse](https://parse.com/) app account. Now we want to implement push notifications using same [Parse](https://parse.com/) account for both apps.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , Its possible . Please refer below screenshot where you can upload multiple p12 certificates file for multiple iOS app. Then you will send pushes according to app e.g. using channels. One channel name for one app, another channel for second app. Also you can add extra field to Installation class so you can send advance push notifications to user by querying users.

[image]

One more [helpful link](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/pushing-to-multiple-ios-apps-simultaneously/)

Answer (score 0):

[Guide](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications)

connected with one parse.com

```
[Parse setApplicationId:@"xxxx"
                  clientKey:@"xxxx"];
```

Get Device Tocan

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
        currentInstallation.channels = @[ @"globle" ];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
NSString * udid=[[[[deviceToken description]
                           stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""]
                          stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""]
                         stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
```

Send PushNotification

```
    NSMutableArray * arrUserParseQuery=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
//add user to send pushNotification
     for (NSString * strObjectId in arrUsers) {
        PFQuery * objUserQuery=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
        [objUserQuery whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:strObjectId];
        [arrUserParseQuery addObject:objUserQuery];
     }
     [pushQuery whereKey:@"UserId" matchesQuery:[PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:arrUserParseQuery]];
     PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
     [push setQuery:pushQuery]; // Set our Installation query
     [push setMessage:@"Notification text"];
     [push sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Errer of push notification %@",error);
     }];
```

you must set **[Certificates](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications-sending-pushes)** in parse.com for send pushNotification.

Comment: Please read carefully my question , my question is that May I connect two ios app with one parse.com app for push notification

Comment: you read my answer at Send PushNotification, you can send may users to notification.